# Wordpress: add tags with links in middle of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to add linked tags to a post but in the middle of the page. We are using it for a portfolio post and want to list some basic details in the middle of everything else. You can see the empty tags area on this page: http://ucdev.inventivewebdesign.com/portfolio_page/lifechurch-phase-i-kidslife/

I have tried adding  and  to the page but it doesn't let me use php in the post.

I then tried to add a plugin that lets me use PHP snippets. It works partially:

```
echo 'Tags: ';
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

It shows Tags: on the page but not the list of tags. I have also tried these:

```
global $post;
foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag)
{
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}

<?php $tags = get_the_tags(); 
if( $tags ) foreach( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
<?php break; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi M I found you also use Wordpress to make the site, so here is my idea for you.
use **add_shortcode('short_code_name','short_code_function')** at the end of **functions.php** file, then add the shortcode **[short_code_name]** to any **textblock** anywhere in your post/page. The following are the steps:

1 open functions.php file under wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php;
2 add a function about displaying the tags on the post page:

```
     add_shortcode('test_tags','test_tags_function');
function test_tags_function(){
    echo 'Tags: ';
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        echo "<ul style=\"list-style-type:none\">";
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
          echo '<li>';
        echo $tag->name . '</li>'; 

      }
      echo "<ul>";
    }
}
```

image:
[image]

3 add **[test_tags]**(example) to a textblock, like: 
[image]

4 if you want the **black dot** in front of your tags, then **delete this part of code**:

```
style=\"list-style-type:none\"
```

[image]

**is this what you like "list of tags"?**

[image]

Comment: I think you are on the right track. The problem is that I am using a custom post type which is portfolio. I think this came with my theme. It doesn't pull that tags and I think it is because it is looking for post tags and not portfolio tags.